# how to shoot at shapes with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am reading this book for Python called "More Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner" and in chapter 4, you create this bomb catching game. I am trying to modify it so you shoot at the bomb or enemy.

I want to be able to draw the bullets using

```
pygame.draw.circle()
```

and so it shoots when you click on the right mouse button, then it hits the enemy and it adds on your score.
By the way - I already know how to add the score on I just need help with shooting the shape :)
if you want to have a look at the original game source file, go here - 
http://www.delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1435459806/relatedfiles/index.asp?isbn=1435459806
and it's in chapter 4, "BombCatcher"

original source code-

```
# Bomb Catcher Game
# Chapter 4

import sys, random, time, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def print_text(font, x, y, text, color=(255,255,255)):
    imgText = font.render(text, True, color)
    screen.blit(imgText, (x,y))


#main program begins
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Bomb Catching Game")
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
white = 255,255,255
red = 220, 50, 50
yellow = 230,230,50
black = 0,0,0

lives = 3
score = 0
clock_start = 0
game_over = True
mouse_x = mouse_y = 0

pos_x = 300
pos_y = 460

bomb_x = random.randint(0,500)
bomb_y = -50
vel_y = 0.7

#repeating loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_x,mouse_y = event.pos
            move_x,move_y = event.rel
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if game_over:
                game_over = False
                lives = 3
                score = 0

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
        sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,100))

    if game_over:
        print_text(font1, 100, 200, "<CLICK TO PLAY>") 
    else:
        #move the bomb
        bomb_y += vel_y

        #has the player missed the bomb?
        if bomb_y > 500:
            bomb_x = random.randint(0, 500)
            bomb_y = -50
            lives -= 1
            if lives == 0:
                game_over = True

        #see if player has caught the bomb
        elif bomb_y > pos_y:
            if bomb_x > pos_x and bomb_x < pos_x + 120:
                score += 10
                bomb_x = random.randint(0, 500)
                bomb_y = -50

        #draw the bomb
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (bomb_x-4,int(bomb_y)-4), 30, 0)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, yellow, (bomb_x,int(bomb_y)), 30, 0)

        #set basket position
        pos_x = mouse_x
        if pos_x < 0:
            pos_x = 0
        elif pos_x > 500:
            pos_x = 500
        #draw basket
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (pos_x-4,pos_y-4,120,40), 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (pos_x,pos_y,120,40), 0)

    #print # of lives
    print_text(font1, 0, 0, "LIVES: " + str(lives))

    #print score
    print_text(font1, 500, 0, "SCORE: " + str(score))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: It would help if you asked a more specific question, but I think you are on the right track with the draw circle stuff. Read this to get a feel for determining if your bullet hits the shape: http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

To check if a button was pressed, you should check for an `event.type : MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`,and then check for the RMB.

In order to shoot, you need some sort of a list, so that there will be many bullets possible.
You can create a simple Bullet class, that will have a draw and move functions.
An example:

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self,position):
        self.x,self.y = position
    def move(self):
        self.position += 5
    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, x, y, 30, 0)
```

This covers the drawing, and movement of your bullets. Apart from this, you should check if bullets do not go off screen, and if they do, remove them from the list.

Collision can be done in many ways. Pygame has a built in method called collide_rect, which checks if 2 rectangles are overlapping. But since you have 2 circles, the method is a bit different.

Since you have 2 circles, you have a distance between them. It's given by this equation:

> D = sqrt((xa-xb)^2+(ya-yb)^2))

If the distance is smaller than `R1 + R2`, then the circles are overlapping. You can then proceed to remove the bullet as well as the bomb.

We can simplify this to:

> (R1+R2)^2 > (xa-xb)^2+(ya-yb)^2)